# NullReferenceException in DragDrop after adding Items to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to implement a dynamic ListBox that contains the "open files" of my program. Those files can be dragged from the ListBox into one of four Canvases.
That works all fine as long as the items are added in XAML before starting the program, however, once I add items to the ListBox via fileList.Items.Add("myitemname"); I get a NullReferenceException if I try to drop (dragging works) them into the Canvas at

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Here the relevant part of my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    InitialDataObject _initData = new InitialDataObject();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    #region DragImage

    private void DragImageStart(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _initData._mousePoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    }

    private void DragImageMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = _initData._mousePoint - mousePos;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && (
        Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
        Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance) && ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem != null))
        {
            var listBox = sender as ListBox;
            var listBoxItem = listBox.SelectedItem;
            DataObject dragData = new DataObject(_initData._dropIdentifier, listBoxItem);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move); 
        }

    }

    private void CanvasDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(_initData._dropIdentifier))
        {
            var item = e.Data.GetData(_initData._dropIdentifier) as ListBoxItem;
            (sender as Canvas).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            DropImage(sender as Canvas, item);
            fileList.UnselectAll();
        }
    }

    private void CanvasDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(_initData._dropIdentifier) || sender == e.Source)
        {
            (sender as Canvas).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 240, 240, 240));
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        } 
    }

    private void DropImage(Canvas targetCanvas, ListBoxItem item)
    {
        //just to check if I got the right item in this method
        MessageBox.Show(item.Content.ToString());
    }

    private void CanvasDragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(_initData._dropIdentifier) || sender == e.Source)
        {
            (sender as Canvas).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void sdfsdf(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        fileList.Items.Add("test");
    }
}

class InitialDataObject
{
    public Point _mousePoint = new Point();
    public readonly string _dropIdentifier = "dropIdentifier";
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,23,0,0" Name="gridSubmain" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Panel.ZIndex="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" MaxWidth="250" MinWidth="250" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Height="Auto" Name="fileList" Width="Auto" Background="#FFE6E6E6" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Panel.ZIndex="1" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="DragImageStart" PreviewMouseMove="DragImageMove" FontSize="16" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2">
        <ListBoxItem Content="dfgdfg" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="sfsdf" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="ghjgh" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="cvbcvb" />
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,196,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="sdfsdf" />
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="gridImage" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" AllowDrop="True" Drop="CanvasDrop" DragEnter="CanvasDragEnter" Background="White" DragLeave="CanvasDragLeave" />
    <Canvas Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Drop="CanvasDrop" DragEnter="CanvasDragEnter" Grid.Column="1" AllowDrop="True" Background="White" DragLeave="CanvasDragLeave"/>
    <Canvas Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Drop="CanvasDrop" DragEnter="CanvasDragEnter" Grid.Row="1" AllowDrop="True" Background="White" DragLeave="CanvasDragLeave"/>
    <Canvas Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Drop="CanvasDrop" DragEnter="CanvasDragEnter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" AllowDrop="True" Background="White" DragLeave="CanvasDragLeave"/>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas why it is working with existing items but not with ones added via fileList.Items.Add("..");? Also, with existing Items the fileList.UnselectAll(); works fine, but the extra added items stay selected and I can't get rid of the selection.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the exception. It shows where in the code the exception happens.

Comment: Where exactly can I find that? After the exception the part "DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move); 
" is selected if that helps.
Also I have been doing testings and it doesn't crash if I remove the MessageBox.Show

Comment: there are several places you have used `as`, like `sender as Canvas, sender as ListBox`, you need to check for null after that. when sender is not type of expected it return null.

Comment: As everything is working perfectly with Items that were added to the ListBox before Runtime in XAML everything should be as expected. If you want I can provide the XAML along with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in you `CanvasDrop` method. You expect ListBoxItem there, but get string, because `SelectedItem` property of list box have different values for items you create in xaml and items you add dynamically.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to actually add ListBoxItems into the ListBox dynamically? Because UnselectAll() doesn't seem to work on the strings.

Comment: Edit: Interesting, changing everything to string instead of ListBoxItem makes it work but doesn't unselect with UnselectAll(); if the items have the same name. It does work with different names.

Comment: That's the answer how to add ListBoxItems: fileList.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem {Content = "test"});

Comment: What do you mean "give the dynamically added items different names"?

Comment: For testing reasons I gave all Items the name "test" (using fileList.Items.Add("test"); But then the UnselectAll(); didn't work

Comment: Thank you fileList.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem {Content = "test"}); did the trick!